# How do I use gallery to view multiple images from external storage using intents when I hava Uris of those images in a list

Tags: java, android

I want to open multiple images in default image viewing apps(gallery, google photos,etc.) from an array list of URIs of images. But what I have achieved so far is that it opens first image in my arraylist contaning URIs of those images. I have android 8.0.

**I have included following in my manifest**

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

**in res/xml/provider_paths**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <!--<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>-->
    <external-path
        name="files_root"
        path="Android/data/${applicationId}"/>
    <external-path
        name="external_storage_root"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

**I am calling this method in my onClickListener of**

```
private void viewImage(ArrayList<String> list) {


    File file = new File(list.get(0));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N ? FileProvider.getUriForFile(mCtx, getPackageName() + ".provider", file) : Uri.fromFile(file),
            "image/jpeg").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    mCtx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to open multiple images in default image viewing apps

There is no `Intent` action for that, sorry.

Comment: then what should I do to view images in fullscreen as the default gallery shows. or do I have to create a custom image viewer?

Comment: @AliAsad: "then what should I do to view images in fullscreen as the default gallery shows" -- have an activity or fragment with a full-screen `ImageView`. "or do I have to create a custom image viewer?" -- yes.